# Find-Module -AllVersions is not producing a list of versions

Tags: powershell

I have a local repository with three (3) versions of a module. However, `Find-Module` does not produce them when using the `-AllVersions` switch. Why is that?

```
PS 09:53  C:\src
>dir .\Repo\

    Directory: C:\src\Repo

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-08-21     11:08           3544 litmod01.1.0.0.nupkg
-a----       2019-08-21     13:57           3705 litmod01.1.1.0.nupkg
-a----       2019-08-21     14:04           3704 litmod01.1.2.0.nupkg

PS 09:53  C:\src
>Find-Module -Repository EdwRepo -Name litmod01

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
1.2.0                litmod01                            EdwRepo              Learning modules 01

PS 09:53  C:\src
>Find-Module -Repository EdwRepo -Name litmod01 -AllVersions
PS 09:53  C:\src
>Get-PSRepository
Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
EdwRepo                   Trusted              C:\src\repo

PS 14:46  C:\src
>Get-Module -Name PowerShellGet

ModuleType Version    Name
---------- -------    ----
Script     2.2.1      PowerShellGet

PS 14:46  C:\src
>($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).ToString()
5.1.17134.858
```

Comment: What is the output of `Get-PSRepository`? IE: is your `EdwRepo` pointing to C:\src\Repo? Also is `litmod01` the same module as `pdwmod01`?

Comment: I have added output from `Get-PSRepository` to the question showing the local repo. Yes, I missed replacing pdw with lit in one command. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Well this is past my knowledge off hand, I cannot reproduce when I use `Publish-Module` to publish different versions of one of my modules to a file share repo. `Find-Module` returns Are you doing something other than `Publish-Module` to put your modules in the repo? (Not sure what that could be) Also, what version is your powerShellGet module?

Comment: @BrandonMcClure - Yes, I am using `Publish-Module`. PowerShellGet 2.2.1 added to question.